# Erro na Serialização de Objetos com Spring data e Spring Web

Tags: spring, jpa, rest, spring-data, jackson

Eu estava criando um simples endpoint de uma entidade e acabei recebendo a seguinte exceção:

```
com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidDefinitionException: No serializer found for class org.hibernate.proxy.pojo.javassist.JavassistLazyInitializer and no properties discovered to create BeanSerializer (to avoid exception, disable SerializationFeature.FAIL_ON_EMPTY_BEANS) (through reference chain: com.logpro.appcidadao.model.imovel.Imovel_$$_jvst35_0["handler"])
```

Com algumas pesquisas, cheguei em uma solução para o problema. Adicionei ao meu application.properites a configuração (`jackson.erialization.FAIL_ON_EMPTY_BEANS=false)` para não serializar propriedades vazias e anotei minha classe da seguinte forma:

```
@JsonIgnoreProperties({"hibernateLazyInitializer", "handler"})
```

Com isso tudo funcionou corretamente. Porém, é onde entra minha dúvida.
Minha classe `Imovel`possui apenas um atributo, que é o id. Como está disparando o erro de lazyInitiliazer se a classe não possui mais nenhum atributo?

Classe Imovel:

```
@Entity
@Table(schema = "cadastro", name = "imovel")
@Data
@Builder
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
//@JsonIgnoreProperties({"hibernateLazyInitializer", "handler"})
public class Imovel {

   @Id
   @Column(name = "imov_id")
   private Integer id;

}
```

1. Spring boot: 2.0.3
2. Spring: 5.0.7

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Então, o problema se dava no meu repositório.
Eu tenho uma classe chamada `ImovelRepository` que estende `JpaRepository`. Em uma versão anterior, eu utilizava o método `findOne` passando o ID do objeto que eu queria carregar. Acontece que na nova API, o método `findOne` não recebe mais um ID, e sim, recebe um `Example`. Com isso, alterei o `findOne` para `getOne`, pensando faria a mesma coisa. Porém, o `getOne` funciona de maneira semelhante ao `getReference`, que deixa a classe em modo lazy. Com isso, eu fui olhar a documentação do spring data 5, e vi que o método que retorna um objeto pesquisando pelo ID é o `findById` (novo nome). 
Trocando para esse método, funcionou corretamente como o esperado.